# how does a computer work out if a value is greater than?

Tags: language-agnostic, binary

I understand basic binary logic and how to do basic addition, subtraction etc. I get that each of the characters in this text is just a binary number representing a number in a charset. The numbers dont really mean anything to the computer. I'm confused however as to how a computer works out that a number is greater than another. what does it do at the bit level?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have two numbers, you can compare each bit, from most significant to least significant, using a 1-bit comparator gate:

[image: eComparator gate]

Of course n-bit comparator gates exist and are described further [here](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/comb_8.html).

Comment: +1 For taking me back with a picture of digital logic gates.  :)

Answer (score 1):

It subtracts one from the other and sees if the result is less than 0 (by checking the highest-order bit, which is 1 on a number less than 0 since computers use 2's complement notation).

http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/2s_comp.htm

Answer (score 1):

Within the processor, often there will be microcode to do operations, using hardwired options, such as add/subtract, that is already there.

So, to do a comparison of an integer the microcode can just do a subtraction, and based on the result determine if one is greater than the other.

Microcode is basically just low-level programs that will be called by assembly, to make it look like there are more commands than is actually hardwired on the processor.

You may find this useful:
http://www.osdata.com/topic/language/asm/intarith.htm

Answer (score 1):

I guess it does a bitwise comparison of two numbers from the most significant bit to the least significant bit, and when they differ, the number with the bit set to "1" is the greater.

In a Big-endian architecture, the comparison of the following Bytes:

A: 0010 1101
B: 0010 1010

would result in A being greatest than B for its 6th bit (from the left) is set to one, while the precedent bits are equal to B.

But this is just a quick theoretic answer, with no concerns about floating point numbers and negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It substracts the two numbers and checks if the result is positive, negative (highest bit - aka "the minus bit" is set), or zero.